How to rewrite this algebraic equation so that its factorization ends up obvious?
While working on an induction exercise, I had $k(2k + 1) + 6(k + 1)$ and I wanted to express that as $(k + 2)(2k + 3)$.  I couldn't do it without expanding the first expression.  I had to write $$k(2k + 1) + 6(k + 1) = 2k^2 + k + 6k + 6 = 2k^2 + 7k + 6$$ so that I could now factor it as $2k^2 + 7k + 6 = (k + 2)(2k + 3)$.
I think I am forced to do this because that $6k$ had to be added to $k$ so that I'd get $7k$.  In other words, I had to mix the terms to then factor it properly.  I would not have found common terms to factor.  Or could I have?  I believe you'll find rewriting ways to put common factors there.  That's what I'm looking for.  A certain technique so that I don't have to look for factors.  By the way, I don't find the factorization of quadratic polynomials easy to find to factor because of the leading coefficient.  It makes my life harder.

You can use the Rational root theorem for $2x^2+7x+6=0$.

Or use quadratic formula to find roots $x_1,x_2$, then $2x^2+7x+6=2(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$

@DietrichBurde, thanks for remind me of the Rational Root Theorem.

$$2k^2+7k+6=2k^2+4k+3k+6=2k(k+2)+3(k+2)=(2k+3)(k+2)$$

Good perception.

Not only yours, it makes my life hard too.
One method is to use the Rational Root Theorem as suggested in the comments.

Another way
The quadratic you have is $$2k^2+7k+6$$
Rewrite it as $$2\left(k^2+\frac{7k}{2}+3\right)$$
Now ignore that "2" for some time. Find two real numbers $a$ and $b$ such $a+b=\frac72$ and $ab=3$
When you'll solve for these two real numbers (which is quite easy) you'll end up with $a=2$ and $b=\frac32$ (actually they're symmetric)

Now rewrite the quadratic as $$2\left(k^2+2k+\frac{3k}{2}+3\right)$$ Now factor out common terms $$2\left(k(k+2)+\frac{3}{2}(k+2)\right)$$
Now use the distributive property and rewrite it as $$2(k+2)\left(k+\frac{3}{2}\right)$$ $$=(k+2)(2k+3)$$

Why do you say that solving $a + b = 7/2$ and $ab = 3$ is quite easy?  You mean by inspection we can find the numbers?

@user1145880 i understand....easy is a subjective term...have a good day...cheers
